# me/newsfeed - where is it in the viadeo account

Tags: viadeo

In viadeo where can a logged in user see the me/newsfeed? I have done multiple posts through the API but for some reason I cannot find it anywhere in my account and I want to check what is happening. When I click "Home" I don't see it on that feed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to leave an answer for anyone else who comes across this. The issue was that Viadeo stopped posting status'es. It looks like because we are not a "strategic partner" we have lost the right - even though the post appears in the returned newsfeed and tells us its successfully posted.